# How to applycolor map ( array) for Image using cv2.LUT

Tags: numpy, opencv, python

I'm a new opencv and I have a trouble.
I have a np.array color and I want to add np.array color to my image
This is the np.array color I want to add

```
turbo_colormap_data = np.array(
    [[0.18995,0.07176,0.23217],
     [0.19483,0.08339,0.26149],
     [0.19956,0.09498,0.29024],
     ..................
     [                        ]) 255
```

I have tried with:

```
cv2.LUT(src,lut,dst)
src = image("XXX.jpg)
lut = turbo_colormap_data
dst = image (YYY.jpg)
```

But I can use it,it's wrong.
If you have a idea or a document,please tell me.
Thank you very much,

This is message error:

```
(lutcn == cn || lutcn == 1) && _lut.total() == 256
&& _lut.isContinuous() && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_8S) in function 'cv::LUT'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can apply my array color to image with method and I can show "image" with cv2.imshow("...",image)

```
channels = [cv2.LUT(image_gray, turbo_colormap_data[:,i]) for i in range(0)]
image = np.dstack(channels)
cv2.imshow("...",image)
```

So but I can not write out with cv2.imwrite,
If you have an ideal or document,please tell me.

Thank you very much,

And Thank you @Ari Cooper-Davis who edited my post.